# how to securely log into mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

I am currently working on a MongoDB, Node, Express app. I'm using mongoose with mongo atlas for my db. I want to login into the db but I also want to have my credentials hashed. At this moment I am storing my credentials in another file but when I try to deploy the website it's not working. Here is my code:

```
mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb+srv://@server.mongodb.net/yelp-camp?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    {
        user: config.user,
        pass: config.pass,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
    },
    (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else console.log("Connected");
    });
```

How can  I use a hashed password to login to mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the dotenv package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

You can securely define your parameters in a `.env` file (for development) and then reference them as `process.env.YOUR_PARAMETER` in your code.

For deploying in Heroku check this documentation to correctly add the config vars that were previously defined in .env:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

NOTE: *your .env file should never be committed to your repo*

Comment: That's the thing. I need something that can allow me to commit to a repo because I'm deploying through the repo using heroku

Comment: Yep, it worked. Thanks for the advice. But what do you mean by that note?

Comment: That for development store your 'secret' variables in a .env file and don't commit it to your Repo. Sharing that kind of information should always be avoided

Comment: What I did was to create those variables using the heroku cli and then I included them in my code as process.env.VAR_NAME. Also, I used process.env.var.PORT and IP for another bug that I have. This is how the code looks now. Is that ok? ```user: process.env.DB_USER,
pass: process.env.DB_PASS,
port = process.env.PORT || 3100,
IP = process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1';```